# Is there any way to set number of variables in SQL query based on length of list?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to get the monthly values from database  according to user's choice and visualize them.
I have checkboxes as you can see below;

[Checkboxes I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHz4W.png)

To get the monthly sales numbers according to user's choice I'm getting the values from checkboxes and create a new list that contains only the values not equal to zero. After that I wrote a Select query where a particular column have any of the values in list. But users can choose only 1 value or 3 values or whatever and my sql query have to change depending on that. If user choose 1 value i have to use only 1 "%s" in my query if they choose 5 values i have to use 5 of it. So i created a bunch of if function where condition is lenght of the list. Is there any way to arrange the number of variables in sql query based on lenght of a list ?

```
def plot(self):
        self.listo=[]
        for val in self.lili:
        
        # self.lili is a list that has all of the checkboxes value in it. Unchecked box values is 0 for all.Checked box values is changing based on month.
        
            val=val.get()
            if val !=0:# I created a empty list and add all the checked values in it.
                self.listo.append(val)   
            else:
                pass
        self.tryn=len(self.listo)# I get the lenght of checked checkboxes.
        
        if self.tryn==0:#If anything is selected it's an error.
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "You have to choose at least one")
        if self.tryn==1:##If 1 values is selected use this query with 1 variable.
        
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(current_sales) FROM targets WHERE nameofmonth=(%s)",(self.listo[0],))
            self.current_sales1=self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(target_sales) FROM targets WHERE nameofmonth=(%s)",(self.listo[0],))
            self.target_sales1=self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
            self.show_plot()
        if self.tryn==2:##If 2 values is selected use this query with 2 variable.
            query=("SELECT SUM(target_sales) FROM targets WHERE (nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s))")
            self.cursor.execute(query,self.listo)
            self.target_sales1=self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
            query2=("SELECT SUM(current_sales) FROM targets WHERE (nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s))")
            self.cursor.execute(query2,self.listo)
            self.current_sales1=self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
            self.show_plot()
        if self.tryn==3:
            query=("SELECT SUM(target_sales) FROM targets WHERE (nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s)) OR nameofmonth=(%s)")
            self.cursor.execute(query,self.listo)
            self.target_sales1=self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
            query2=("SELECT SUM(current_sales) FROM targets WHERE (nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s)) OR nameofmonth=(%s)")
            self.cursor.execute(query2,self.listo)
            self.current_sales1=self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
            self.show_plot()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to do this.
I created a string and multiply it with lenght of the list that contains the values of checked checkboxes.

```
query="WHERE "+"nameofmonth=(%s) OR "*self.tryn
```

For getting rid of the extra OR and space at the end;

```
query=query[:-3]
```

At the and i just formatted my query by using this variable.

You can see the full function and explanations here;

```
def plot(self):
            self.listo=[]
            for val in self.lili:
            
            # self.lili is a list that has all of the checkboxes value in it. Unchecked box values is 0 for all.Checked box values is changing based on month.
            
                val=val.get()
                if val !=0:# I created a empty list and add all the checked values in it.
                    self.listo.append(val)   
                else:
                    pass
            self.tryn=len(self.listo)# I get the lenght of checked checkboxes.
            
            query="WHERE "+"nameofmonth=(%s) OR "*self.tryn 
            #Creating a string variable for my query condition and multiplying it with lenght of the check box values.
            #For example if 3 boxes checked by user we get something like that "WHERE nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s) OR "
            query=query[:-3]
            #Getting rid of the extra OR and space at the end. 
            query2="WHERE "+"nameofmonth=(%s) OR "*self.tryn
            #Couldnt use one query for 2 execute function so i just created another one and it worked xd
            query2=query2[:-3]
            
            query=("SELECT SUM(current_sales) FROM targets {}".format(query))
            #Using this query i get this output (for 3 checked checkboxes)
            #("SELECT SUM(current_sales) FROM targets WHERE nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s) OR nameofmonth=(%s))
            self.cursor.execute(query,self.listo)
            #Executing the query by using the list that has the values from checkboxes where values are not equal to zero.
            self.current_sales1=self.cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
            #Getting the SUM of the column i want in INT type.
```